# Copying folders in Python

Tags: python

I have a python script that reads a text file and copied files in a directory that matches that name. I know how to move files however not folders.

Here is my script:

```
#If the string matches a file name move it to a new directory
dst = r"xxx"

with open('Names.txt') as my_file:
    for filename in my_file:
        src = os.path.join(r"V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures") # .strip() to avoid un-wanted white spaces
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(src, filename.strip()), os.path.join(dst, filename.strip()))
```

Now this script can only copy files however I do not know how to make it move folders.

Comment: shutil.copy doesn't move the file, it copies it.

Comment: Yes however it is not copying the folders, do I need to use the move

Comment: @PyMan: Is your question "How to make it move a folder?" or "Why doesn't `copy` work with folders?" Your question is unclear.

Comment: @S3DEV: Well, unless the move is within the same file system, in which case moving is just "atomic rename of folder".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move folders **using shutil in the same way as files**. Assume that you have a folder '*source*' with files inside it. And you want to move it with all the contained files to a '*target*' directory. You can do it in that way:

```
import shutil

original = r'source'
target = r'target'

shutil.move(original, target)
```

Tested and works as expected:)
In this example both directories - 'source' and 'target' located in current directory. In other cases you can use *full path where the directory is currently stored\directory name* instead of folder name.

More examples - [here](https://datatofish.com/move-file-python/).

Answer (score 1):

```
# Source path  
source = '<your-source'   
# Destination path  
destination = '<your-dect>'   
# Move the content of 
# source to destination
# using shutil.copytree() as parameter 
dest = shutil.move(source, destination, 
      copy_function = shutil.copytree)
```

Comment: `copytree` is already used automatically by `shutil.move`, when needed, for directories. Plain `shutil.move` works fine without specifying the `copy_function` at all (and I'm not sure passing `copytree` is even legal).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your updated question, I suspect you just need to know how to *copy* a folder, not *move* it, the same way you copy files. The plain `copy` function doesn't handle this (it's file-oriented), but you can use [the `shutil.copytree` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) instead.

```
#If the string matches a file name move it to a new directory
dst = r"xxx"

with open('Names.txt') as my_file:
    for filename in my_file:
        filename = filename.strip()  # .strip() to avoid un-wanted white spaces
        src = os.path.join(r"V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures", filename)
        if os.path.isdir(src):
            shutil.copytree(src, os.path.join(dst, filename))
        else:
            shutil.copy(src, os.path.join(dst, filename))
```